# How was this calculated $(1-1/z)^{(\frac{-1}{3})}=(1+\frac{1}{3z}+\dots)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

*Background: a simplification step from an interesting [longer problem here](http://mymathforum.com/complex-analysis/35091-solutions-problems-schaum-s-complex-variables.html#post153638) where the residue is needed so only the first two numbers are needed.
$$(1-\tfrac1z)^{-\frac13}=(1+\tfrac1{3z}+\cdots)$$
Was the likely step to compute the cube root: $(1+\frac{1}{z}+(\frac{1}{z})^2\dots)^{\frac{1}{3}}$?
If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Looks like it is using the binomial theorem: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialTheorem.html

Do you have any conditions on $z$? To use binomial theorem we need $|1/z|<1$.

Comment: I always get confused with negative fractions and infinity. So the second coefficient is ${-1/3 \choose m}=\frac{(-1/3)(-4/3)\dots(-(3m-1)/3)}{m!}$ where we choose m=1? The laurent series requires z>1 for the contour to be valid.

Comment: That's what it is. $(-1)^{m}*(-1/z)^m$ cancels the negatives. Thanks!

Comment: As long as only the first two coefficients of that series (the first being the trivial $1$) are shown, it is impossible to guess what the series is at all. The second coefficient is clear form the chain rule: $(x\mapsto(1-x)^{-1/3})'(0)=(-\frac13)(-1)=\frac13$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering $$A=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1-\frac{1}{z}}}$$ let for simplicity $z=\frac 1x$ to make $$A=(1-x)^{-1/3}$$ and use either the generalized binomial theorem or Taylor series around $x=0$. This will give $$A=1+\frac{x}{3}+\frac{2 x^2}{9}+\frac{14 x^3}{81}+\frac{35 x^4}{243}+\frac{91
   x^5}{729}+O\left(x^6\right)$$ Replace back $x$ by $\frac 1z$ to get $$A=1+\frac{1}{3 z}+\frac{2}{9 z^2}+\frac{14}{81 z^3}+\frac{35}{243 z^4}+\frac{91}{729
   z^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^6}\right)$$

For illustration purposes, using $z=2$, the above expansion gives $\frac{29317}{23328}\approx 1.25673$ while the exact value $\sqrt[3]{2}\approx 1.25992$. For sure, it will be better and better when $z$ will increase.

For example using $z=10$, the above expansion gives $\frac{75505741}{72900000}\approx 1.035744047$ while the exact value $\approx 1.035744169$.

Comment: yes, calculating the first and second derivative here is another quick way to get a laurent series from the taylor series $a_{-1}=(-)(-)\frac{1/3}{1!}, a_{-2}=(-)(-)\frac{1/3*4/3}{2!}$ Forgot about that.